# The program "Any Video Converter Professional" is not refreshing when I change to a new blank DVD disc

Tags: video-conversion

the program "any video converter professional" is not refreshing when I change DVD

I have to restart the program

Is there any way to get it to realise that the DVD has been changed without restarting the program.

For example, you see three tabs at the top. "convert video", "burn dvd" ,  "play video".

I click the "burn DVD" tab, then click "add video(s)" and I pick an MP4 to add. I make sure the box is ticked. And I click "burn now".  And that works that burns to my DVD+R DVD.

[image]

When it's nearly done it says "finalizing writing" on the bottom. And when done it says it's done and the DVD ejects. All fine.

I can pop it back in, play it.

Or I can take it out and put a new blank DVD+R DVD in there.

Then if I click "burn now" it says

[image]

The only way that it recognises that I put a new DVD+R disc in there is if I restart Any Video Converter (which isn't a big deal as it's a small program, though I Have to click "add video(s)" again. And I'm wondering if there is a refresh button somewhere that I haven't seen. That will make it realise that I put a new blank DVD in there?

Comment: Sounds like a program bug, I would contact the company that sells it.>>>>https://www.any-video-converter.com/contact.php

Comment: @Moab yeah, not yet resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the program "any video converter", that is not yet resolved.

There is a similar program though, called Wondershare uniconverter that is extremely similar looking, and doesn't have that issue.

Both "any video converter" and "wondershare uniconverter", are not free. The trial version only does part of the file.

Below is an image of wondershare uniconverter

[image]